# PHP refuses to echo strings shorter than 8 characters

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to debug some code and do the following:

```
echo "asd";
exit;
```

The exit happens but the echo is not shown. After some hair pulling I have discovered that if I make the string 8 characters or more then the string IS echoed.

```
echo "12345678";
exit;
```

I assume this has something to do with output buffering or similar and have tried disabling it etc. but to no avail.

Comment: Interesting find. but I checked it echoes even 1 character

Comment: This needs more information. What browser, what web server, what exact testing method?

Comment: maybe an ob_start(); somewhere?

Comment: I checked. It works properly. asd is displayed.

Comment: FYI: try using Xdebug or similar to debug in working with frame works.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was not with PHP but with Chrome caching when viewing source.

It is described in this question in detail.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746713/why-does-chrome-show-different-page-source